# changing the color of the underline or space between the title and body of popover bootstrap in react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm new to StackOverflow so sorry if I'm not asking the question right, anyways.

I've tried searching it up but couldn't find a way to change the color of space that's usually grey between the title and body (that acts as a breaker or underline in the popover)

[image: picture of a popover I've created]

Comment: can you support an code for your mention problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
.popover-title {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e97575;
}
```

Comment: wow, that actually works, thanks Suresh. Dam, surprised by how quick the responses are.